Concurrent table operations in Databricks
I'm running a databricks workflow with for each loop task and the nested task has notebook which is set to create table or update table accordingly
but it is failing because of concurrent load issues, i'm running the loop for 2 brand market channel combinations but it is failing consistently
below is the code which was written for single brand market channel combination
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from utils.spark_data_utils import spark_drop_and_insert
from utils.operators import to_bool
from modules.embeddings import TextToEmbeddings
from utils.table_parameters import OutputDBName, SourceTables

# dbutils.widgets.dropdown("embedding_type", "fasttext", ["fasttext", "glove", "fashionclip"])
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("overwrite", "False", ["False", "True"])

# embedding_type = dbutils.widgets.get("embedding_type")
overwrite = to_bool(dbutils.widgets.get("overwrite"))

dbutils.widgets.dropdown("Deployment_env_name", "DNA_DEV", ["DNA_DEV", "DNA_PROD", "DNA_STAGE", "ENTANA_PROD"])
Deployment_env_name = dbutils.widgets.get('Deployment_env_name')
write_schema = str(OutputDBName[Deployment_env_name].value['write_schema'])
print(f"write_schema: {write_schema}")

# Retrieve filter widget values
dbutils.widgets.text("brd_id", "")
dbutils.widgets.text("mkt_id", "")
dbutils.widgets.text("chnl_id", "")

brd_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("brd_id")))
mkt_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("mkt_id")))
chnl_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("chnl_id")))

def load_latest_rows(table_name):
    # Load the data from the specified table
    df = spark.table(table_name)

    # Find the latest timestamp in the dataset
    latest_timestamp = df.agg(F.max("last_processed_timestamp")).collect()[0][0]

    # Filter the rows with the latest timestamp
    latest_rows = df.filter(df.last_processed_timestamp == latest_timestamp)
    
    return latest_rows

def apply_filters(df):
    """
    Applies the specified filters to the DataFrame.
    
    Parameters:
    ----------
    df : SparkDataFrame
        The input Spark DataFrame.
    
    Returns:
    -------
    SparkDataFrame
        The filtered Spark DataFrame.
    """
    return df.filter(
        (F.col("brd_id") == brd_id) &
        (F.col("mkt_id") == mkt_id) &
        (F.col("chnl_id") == chnl_id)
    )

def process_embeddings():
    input_table_name = f"{write_schema}.drapr_product_attributes"
    output_table_name = f"{write_schema}.drapr_product_attributes_embeddings"

    embed_columns = ['drapr_color','drapr_gender','drapr_pattern','drapr_fit','drapr_season','drapr_style','drapr_sleeve_length','drapr_occasion','drapr_comfort','drapr_fastenings','drapr_cut','drapr_age','drapr_material','drapr_affordability','drapr_product_attributes']   

    ### IF TABLE DOES NOT EXIST OR OVERWRITE IS TRUE -> Create Table
    if not spark.catalog.tableExists(output_table_name) or overwrite:
        
        spark.sql(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {output_table_name}")
        print(f"CREATING TABLE: {output_table_name}")

        # Load and filter the input data
        print("Applying filters to input data")
        input_df = spark.table(input_table_name)
        filtered_input_df = apply_filters(input_df)
        
        print("Running Fasttext Embeddings")
        converter_fasttext = TextToEmbeddings(
            spark_dataframe = filtered_input_df,
            embedding_type = "fasttext",
            preprocess_text = False,
        )
        
        staged_embeddings_fasttext = converter_fasttext.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

        print("Running Glove Embeddings")
        converter_glove = TextToEmbeddings(
            spark_dataframe = staged_embeddings_fasttext,
            embedding_type = "glove",
            preprocess_text = False,
        )
        
        staged_embeddings_glove = converter_glove.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

        print(f"Saving table: {output_table_name}")
        partition_columns = ['brd_id', 'mkt_id', 'chnl_id', "brd_division_id"]
        staged_embeddings_glove.orderBy(partition_columns).write.mode("overwrite")\
                    .option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
                    .saveAsTable(output_table_name)

        spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {output_table_name} OWNER TO `Azure-DataScienceAndAutomation-ABBF-Dev`")
        spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {output_table_name} CLUSTER BY (brd_id, mkt_id, chnl_id, brd_division_id)")
    else:

        print("Running Fasttext Embeddings")
        latest_rows = load_latest_rows(input_table_name)
        filtered_latest_rows = apply_filters(latest_rows)
        
        converter_fasttext = TextToEmbeddings(
            spark_dataframe = filtered_latest_rows,
            embedding_type = "fasttext",
            preprocess_text = False,
        )
        
        staged_embeddings_fasttext = converter_fasttext.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

        print("Running Glove Embeddings")
        converter_glove = TextToEmbeddings(
            spark_dataframe = staged_embeddings_fasttext,
            embedding_type = "glove",
            preprocess_text = False,
        )
        
        staged_embeddings_glove = converter_glove.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

        print(f"RUNNING DROP AND INSERT INTO TABLE: {output_table_name}")
        num_inserted = spark_drop_and_insert(
            staged_embeddings_glove, 
            output_table_name, 
            ["assorted_customer_choice_id", "univ_scls_id", "brd_division_id"]
        )
        print(f"Inserted {num_inserted} rows")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  process_embeddings()

adding the function below for spark_drop_and_insert which was used above
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
def spark_drop_and_insert(dataframe: SparkDataFrame, table_name: str, primary_keys: list[str], timestamp_col: str = "last_processed_timestamp"):

  # Add the timestamp column to the DataFrame
  dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(timestamp_col, current_timestamp())

  # Create a temporary view from the DataFrame
  temp_view_name = "temp_drop_insert_view"
  dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_view_name)

  # Construct the delete and insert SQL queries
  primary_key_conditions = " AND ".join([f"target.{key} = source.{key}" for key in primary_keys])

  delete_query = f"""
  DELETE FROM {table_name} AS target
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM {temp_view_name} AS source
    WHERE {primary_key_conditions}
  )
  """

  insert_columns = ", ".join(dataframe.columns)
  insert_values = ", ".join([f"source.{col}" for col in dataframe.columns])

  insert_query = f"""
  INSERT INTO {table_name} ({insert_columns})
  SELECT {insert_values}
  FROM {temp_view_name} AS source
  """

  # Execute the delete and insert queries
  spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  spark.sql(delete_query)
  spark.sql(insert_query)

  num_inserted = dataframe.count()
  print(">> Drop and insert query executed")
  return num_inserted

this is what i tried
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from utils.operators import to_bool
from modules.embeddings import TextToEmbeddings
from utils.table_parameters import OutputDBName, SourceTables

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
from delta.tables import DeltaTable

# Initialize Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ConcurrentEmbeddings").getOrCreate()

# Set up widgets
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("overwrite", "False", ["False", "True"])
overwrite = to_bool(dbutils.widgets.get("overwrite"))

dbutils.widgets.dropdown("Deployment_env_name", "DNA_DEV", ["DNA_DEV", "DNA_PROD", "DNA_STAGE", "ENTANA_PROD"])
Deployment_env_name = dbutils.widgets.get('Deployment_env_name')
write_schema = str(OutputDBName[Deployment_env_name].value['write_schema'])
print(f"write_schema: {write_schema}")

# Retrieve filter widget values
dbutils.widgets.text("brd_id", "")
dbutils.widgets.text("mkt_id", "")
dbutils.widgets.text("chnl_id", "")

brd_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("brd_id")))
mkt_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("mkt_id")))
chnl_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("chnl_id")))

def load_latest_rows(table_name):
    """
    Loads the latest rows from the specified table based on the 'last_processed_timestamp'.
    """
    df = spark.table(table_name)
    latest_timestamp = df.agg(F.max("last_processed_timestamp")).collect()[0][0]
    latest_rows = df.filter(df.last_processed_timestamp == latest_timestamp)
    return latest_rows

def apply_filters(df):
    """
    Applies the specified filters to the DataFrame.

    Parameters:
    ----------
    df : SparkDataFrame
        The input Spark DataFrame.

    Returns:
    -------
    SparkDataFrame
        The filtered Spark DataFrame.
    """
    return df.filter(
        (F.col("brd_id") == brd_id) &
        (F.col("mkt_id") == mkt_id) &
        (F.col("chnl_id") == chnl_id)
    )

def spark_merge_upsert(dataframe: SparkDataFrame, table_name: str, primary_keys: list[str], timestamp_col: str = "last_processed_timestamp"):
    """
    Performs an upsert operation on a Delta table using a DataFrame.
    This function merges the DataFrame into the target Delta table based on the specified primary keys.
    It updates existing records and inserts new records as necessary. 
    A timestamp column is updated or added to indicate the last processed time.

    Parameters:
    - dataframe (SparkDataFrame): The DataFrame containing the data to be upserted.
    - table_name (str): The name of the target Delta table.
    - primary_keys (list[str]): A list of column names that serve as primary keys for the merge operation.
    - timestamp_col (str, optional): The name of the timestamp column to be updated or added, indicating when the record was last processed. Defaults to "last_processed_timestamp".

    Returns:
    - None
    """
    # Add the timestamp column to the DataFrame
    dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(timestamp_col, current_timestamp())

    # Check if the Delta table exists
    if DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, table_name):
        delta_table = DeltaTable.forName(spark, table_name)
        
        # Construct merge condition
        merge_condition = " AND ".join([f"target.{key} = source.{key}" for key in primary_keys])

        # Perform the merge
        try:
            delta_table.alias("target").merge(
                dataframe.alias("source"),
                merge_condition
            ).whenMatchedUpdateAll(
            ).whenNotMatchedInsertAll(
            ).execute()
            print(f"Upsert completed successfully for table {table_name}.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Upsert failed for table {table_name}: {e}")
            raise
    else:
        # If the table does not exist, create it
        try:
            dataframe.write.format("delta")\
                .mode("overwrite")\
                .option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
                .partitionBy(['brd_id', 'mkt_id', 'chnl_id', "brd_division_id"])\
                .saveAsTable(table_name)
            
            # Set table properties
            spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {table_name} OWNER TO `Azure-DataScienceAndAutomation-ABBF-Dev`")
            spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {table_name} CLUSTER BY (brd_id, mkt_id, chnl_id, brd_division_id)")
            print(f"Table {table_name} created successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Table creation failed for {table_name}: {e}")
            raise

def process_embeddings():
    input_table_name = f"{write_schema}.drapr_product_attributes"
    output_table_name = f"{write_schema}.drapr_product_attributes_embeddings"

    embed_columns = [
        'drapr_color','drapr_gender','drapr_pattern','drapr_fit','drapr_season',
        'drapr_style','drapr_sleeve_length','drapr_occasion','drapr_comfort',
        'drapr_fastenings','drapr_cut','drapr_age','drapr_material',
        'drapr_affordability','drapr_product_attributes'
    ]   

    # Define primary keys for upsert
    primary_keys = ["assorted_customer_choice_id", "univ_scls_id", "brd_division_id"]

    # Determine if the table exists
    table_exists = DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, output_table_name)

    if overwrite or not table_exists:
        # Handle table creation or overwrite in a concurrency-safe manner using Delta Lake
        if not table_exists:
            print(f"Creating Delta table: {output_table_name}")
        elif overwrite:
            print(f"Overwriting Delta table: {output_table_name}")

        try:
            # Load and filter the input data
            print("Applying filters to input data")
            input_df = spark.table(input_table_name)
            filtered_input_df = apply_filters(input_df)
            
            # Initialize TextToEmbeddings for Fasttext
            print("Running Fasttext Embeddings")
            converter_fasttext = TextToEmbeddings(
                spark_dataframe=filtered_input_df,
                embedding_type="fasttext",
                preprocess_text=False,
            )
            
            staged_embeddings_fasttext = converter_fasttext.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

            # Initialize TextToEmbeddings for Glove
            print("Running Glove Embeddings")
            converter_glove = TextToEmbeddings(
                spark_dataframe=staged_embeddings_fasttext,
                embedding_type="glove",
                preprocess_text=False,
            )
            
            staged_embeddings_glove = converter_glove.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

            # Write to Delta table (create or overwrite)
            print(f"Saving table: {output_table_name}")
            staged_embeddings_glove.write.format("delta")\
                .mode("overwrite")\
                .option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
                .partitionBy(['brd_id', 'mkt_id', 'chnl_id', "brd_division_id"])\
                .saveAsTable(output_table_name)
            
            # Set table properties
            spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {output_table_name} OWNER TO `Azure-DataScienceAndAutomation-ABBF-Dev`")
            spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {output_table_name} CLUSTER BY (brd_id, mkt_id, chnl_id, brd_division_id)")
            print(f"Table {output_table_name} {'created' if not table_exists else 'overwritten'} successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to create or overwrite table {output_table_name}: {e}")
            raise
    else:
        # Perform upsert using Delta Lake's MERGE
        print(f"Performing upsert into Delta table: {output_table_name}")
        
        try:
            # Load latest rows
            latest_rows = load_latest_rows(input_table_name)
            filtered_latest_rows = apply_filters(latest_rows)

            # Check if there are any latest rows to process
            if filtered_latest_rows.rdd.isEmpty():
                print("No new or updated records found for upsert.")
                return

            # Run embeddings on the latest filtered rows
            print("Running Fasttext Embeddings on latest rows")
            converter_fasttext_latest = TextToEmbeddings(
                spark_dataframe=filtered_latest_rows,
                embedding_type="fasttext",
                preprocess_text=False,
            )
            staged_embeddings_fasttext_latest = converter_fasttext_latest.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

            print("Running Glove Embeddings on latest rows")
            converter_glove_latest = TextToEmbeddings(
                spark_dataframe=staged_embeddings_fasttext_latest,
                embedding_type="glove",
                preprocess_text=False,
            )
            staged_embeddings_glove_latest = converter_glove_latest.stage_embeddings(embed_columns)

            # Perform merge upsert
            spark_merge_upsert(staged_embeddings_glove_latest, output_table_name, primary_keys)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Upsert failed for table {output_table_name}: {e}")
            raise

# Execute the processing function
process_embeddings()


and the job is failing with the modification i did, so im not sure how to concurrently create or update table for different iterations of brd_id, mkt_id and chnl_id which is set to run concurrently
can anyone please help me solve this issue

What a is the error you getting.add those details

Does below solution helped you?

That is because the concurrent operations is trying to access the same delta files while performing upsert.
To avoid this conflict you partition your delta table according to the
brd_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("brd_id")))
mkt_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("mkt_id")))
chnl_id = int(float(dbutils.widgets.get("chnl_id")))

and give them in merge condition by specifying the brd_id, mkt_id and chnl_id
merge_condition  +  F" AND target.brd_id = {brd_id} AND target.mkt_id = {mkt_id} AND target.chnl_id = {chnl_id}"

Condition will be something like below
'target.assorted_customer_choice_id = source.assorted_customer_choice_id AND target.univ_scls_id = source.univ_scls_id AND target.brd_division_id = source.brd_division_id AND target.brd_id = 17 AND target.mkt_id = 15 AND target.chnl_id = 20'

Now, by giving this condition it is safe to run concurrent operations on different brd_id, mkt_id and chnl_id.
Check more about this kind of conflicts handling here
